# Get class name of generic parameter passed typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

How do i get the class name of the generic parameter passed

```
class Sample<T>{ 
    public getTypeName(): void { 
        alert(T.name)
        //or
        alert(new T().constructor.name)
    }
}
class Person { 
    public FullName:string
}
new Sample<Person>().getTypeName()
```

I need the output to be printed as "***Person***" ?

Comment: Typescript type information is entirely compile-time. The transpiled Javascript has none of this information left.

Answer (score 5):

While type generic types are erased at compiler time, you can pass in the constructor of the class and get the name of that:

```
class Sample<T>{ 
    public constructor(public tCtor: new (...args:any[]) => T){}
    public getTypeName(): void { 
        console.log(this.tCtor.name)
    }
}
class Person { 
    public FullName!:string
}
new Sample(Person).getTypeName()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I cannot comment to the [answer of Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906728/14022790):

This only makes sense, if the context of the caller is non-generic, which might often not be the case. If I only have a generic parameter at hand (for example in a generic class), there is no way to create a runtime instance of it's instanciated type or use the name of the instanciated type, even if the needed information should be available at compile time. It's a pity for people which are used to C++ Templates or Java/C# Generics.